# Proper drive partitioning in Linux for Oracle

Tags: oracle, partitioning, redhat

I have a current production physical server running on RHEL and I'm going to be building a new Oracle Linux VM to take it's place. Below is a listing of the existing physical drive partitions.

Can anyone tell me why the previous DBA would have created all of these and how you might have created these differently if it was your VM that you were going to build?

It just seems to have more partitions than what I've seen in the past.

[image]

The other server looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Historical? Aren't these fairly standard logical volumes created by the RHEL installer? It could be it just grew from the standard install.

Comment: As Colin said, this was pretty standard before ASM came along...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all looks fairly logical from a historical point of view.  You generally want to separate out your redo, data, exports, backups etc to separate disks if you can.  You may find that these are all mounted from different physical disks which is the 'correct' way of doing things (e.g. you don't want your data and redo on the same disks if you can help it).

However, from my point of view it's a fairly "old school" build.

For the Oracle 11gR2 environments that I am currently building, I only have the following Oracle specific mounts:

```
/u01/ (oracle homes)
+FRA (ASM) _or_ /FRA (depending on requirements)
+DATA (ASM)
/backups/ (so that Netbackup plays nicely with RMAN backupsets)
```

I could split it up more, but seeing as everything's coming from the same SAN device and I can't persuade my infrastructure team to spend the time ensuring that they're all coming from different LUNs/physical disks, I'm not too worried yet.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Since it will be within the container of a VM then it will only have 2 "virtual disks" 1 IDE to boot from (I still hate Hyper-V :P ) and 1 SCSI (performs decently in Hyper-V) So I'll just over provision the size of the VHDX to plan for a couple of years of growth, create the mounts and call it a day :) THANKS!